# jQuery DataTables not working special characters results in search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, accent-insensitive

I am trying to search some words with special characters in jQuery Datatables plugin.

There are some results in datatable like this:

```
Peinado, Alma_María
Aguilar Castillo, Antonio José
```

When I try to search "alma_maría", the first result is shown:

```
Peinado, Alma_María
```

When I try "alma_maria" (note that I am using character "i" instead "í"), nothing is shown.

Screenshot 1:

[image: Trying to search "alma_maría"]

Screenshot 2:

[image: Trying to search "alma_maria"]

Is there any way to configure Datatables to show special characters results when I search without special characters?

My HTML/Javascript code:

```
<table class="display table table-bordered table-striped" id="table-colegiados">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>{$TXT.nombre}</th>
    <th>{$TXT.ciudad}</th>
    <th>{$TXT.email}</th>
    <th>{$TXT.telefono}</th>
    <th>{$TXT.dni}</th>
    <th>{$TXT.colegiado}</th>
    <th>{$TXT.asesor}</th>
    <th>{$TXT.editar}</th>
    <th>{$TXT.borrar}</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnGetFilteredNodes = function ( oSettings )
    {
        var anRows = [];
        for ( var i=0, iLen=oSettings.aiDisplay.length ; i<iLen ; i++ ) {
            var nRow = oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ].nTr;
            anRows.push( nRow );
        }
        return anRows;
    };
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
        if ( oSettings.nTable == document.getElementById( 'table-colegiados' )){
            var asesor = aData[6];
            var checked = $('#checkbox_asesores').is(':checked');
            if (checked) {
                if (asesor == '1') {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
    var oTable = $('#table-colegiados').dataTable({
            "aaSorting": [ [0,'asc'] ],
            'iDisplayLength': 25,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": false,
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "ajax/getColegiados.php",
            "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                    fnCallback(json)
                } );
            }
    });
    $('#checkbox_asesores').on("click", function(e) {
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: which database u r using ?

Comment: What do you mean? Data is from a JSON.

Comment: you can try this http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/type-based/accent-neutralise

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/416mvzws/

Comment: I think the "accent neutralise" plugin that KishoreSahas posted is the answer that you're looking for, but I'd still like to share this interesting article about the problem: http://alistapart.com/article/accent-folding-for-auto-complete

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know why, but "Accent Neutralisation" is not working for me.

I had a creative idea that worked like a charm.

I used in the PHP side a function like this:

```
public function cleanString($String)
{
    $String = str_replace(array('á','à','â','ã','ª','ä'), "a", $String);
    $String = str_replace(array('Á','À','Â','Ã','Ä'), "a", $String);
    $String = str_replace(array('Í','Ì','Î','Ï'), "i", $String);
    $String = str_replace(array('í','ì','î','ï'), "i", $String);
    $String = str_replace(array('é','è','ê','ë'), "e", $String);
    $String = str_replace(array('É','È','Ê','Ë'), "e", $String);
    $String = str_replace(array('ó','ò','ô','õ','ö','º'), "o", $String);
    $String = str_replace(array('Ó','Ò','Ô','Õ','Ö'), "o", $String);
    $String = str_replace(array('ú','ù','û','ü'), "u", $String);
    $String = str_replace(array('Ú','Ù','Û','Ü'), "u", $String);
    $String = str_replace(array('[','^','´','`','¨','~',']'), "", $String);
    $String = str_replace("ç", "c", $String);
    $String = str_replace("Ç", "C", $String);
    $String = str_replace("ñ", "n", $String);
    $String = str_replace("Ñ", "N", $String);
    $String = str_replace("Ý", "Y", $String);
    $String = str_replace("ý", "y", $String);
    $String = str_replace("&aacute;", "a", $String);
    $String = str_replace("&Aacute;", "a", $String);
    $String = str_replace("&eacute;", "e", $String);
    $String = str_replace("&Eacute;", "e", $String);
    $String = str_replace("&iacute;", "i", $String);
    $String = str_replace("&Iacute;", "i", $String);
    $String = str_replace("&oacute;", "o", $String);
    $String = str_replace("&Oacute;", "o", $String);
    $String = str_replace("&uacute;", "u", $String);
    $String = str_replace("&Uacute;", "u", $String);
    return $String;
}
```

To replace special chars with its non-special-char version.

Then added to the JSON, in the "name" field, this non-specialchars version inside a HTML comment.

I had:

```
$arrayJson = array();
foreach ($arrayUsers as $item) {
    $arrayJson[] = array(
        $item['name'],
        $item['city'],
        $item['email'],
        $item['phone'],
        $item['id'],
        $item['colleged'],
        $item['asesor']
    );
}
$jsonStr = json_encode($arrayJson);
```

Now I have:

```
$arrayJson = array();
foreach ($arrayUsers as $item) {
    $cleanName = $Utils->cleanString($item['name']);
    $arrayJson[] = array(
        '<!-- ' . $cleanName . ' -->' . $item['name'],
        $item['city'],
        $item['email'],
        $item['phone'],
        $item['id'],
        $item['colleged'],
        $item['asesor']
    );
}
$jsonStr = json_encode($arrayJson);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Accent neutralisation. and there is ready plugin for it.

http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/type-based/accent-neutralise

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['string'] = function ( data ) {
return ! data ?
    '' :
    typeof data === 'string' ?
        data
            .replace( /\n/g, ' ' )
            .replace( /á/g, 'a' )
            .replace( /é/g, 'e' )
            .replace( /í/g, 'i' )
            .replace( /ó/g, 'o' )
            .replace( /ú/g, 'u' )
            .replace( /ê/g, 'e' )
            .replace( /î/g, 'i' )
            .replace( /ô/g, 'o' )
            .replace( /è/g, 'e' )
            .replace( /ï/g, 'i' )
            .replace( /ü/g, 'u' )
            .replace( /ç/g, 'c' ) :
        data;
};
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/416mvzws/